# dropdown and radio button not retrieving while editing the form

Tags: php, html, mysql, form-submit

Please help me!!!
I am creating a form with all insert update delete operations. Till the time I was creating with text box it was all good but when I started using radio button in gender and drop-down field in category it started giving problem. I don't have much knowledge in php. I tried using many option online but was not able to fix. The insert form works well with drop-down and radio button fields but when it comes to edit the drop-down and radio button's, its selected value is not retrieved from database. Below is my code I found some checked options for gender but it is not working. please anybody check my code and tell me what i am missing.

```html
my edit.php code 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>library</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
    <link href='https://sites.google.com/site/99webdemos/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.responsive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
      jQuery(".form-message").fadeOut(10000);
    });
    </script>
   

<style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
.ie7 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

</style></head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
    <div id="art-header-bg" class="clearfix">
            </div>
    <div id="art-hmenu-bg" class="art-bar art-nav clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<header class="art-header clearfix">


    <div class="art-shapes">
<h1 class="art-headline" data-left="0.5%">
    <a  href="http://www.99demos.blogspot.com" target="_blank">library</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="art-slogan" data-left="87.05%"><a href="http://99demos.blogspot.in/2014/06/createreadupdate-delete-with-image.html"></a></h2>


            </div>

<nav class="art-nav clearfix">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li></ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>

                    
</header>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content clearfix"><article class="art-post art-article">
                                <h2 class="art-postheader">customer form</h2>
                                                
                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <br>
        
        
<?php
ob_start(); 
include('include/connect.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

 $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
         $age = $_POST["age"];`enter code here`
         $gender = $_POST["gender"];
         $martial = $_POST["martial"];
         $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
                          $category= $_POST["category"];
              
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
     $file='uploads/'.$row['image'];
     @unlink($file);
                 $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
              $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
     $image_name=time().".".$ext;
              $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
  }
  else
  {
    $image_name=$row['image'];
  }
  
     $sqlAdd ="update tbl_emp set name='".$name."', age='".$age."', gender='".$gender."', martial='".$martial."', contact='".$contact."', email='".$email."', location='".$location."', category='".$category."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
     mysql_query($sqlAdd);
         header("Location:add.php?id=".@$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
   exit;
    }  
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
       $age = $_POST["age"];
       $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        $martial = $_POST["martial"];
        $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
                         $category= $_POST["category"];
               
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
   $image_name=time().".".$ext;

            $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
        }
        $sqlAdd = mysql_query("insert into tbl_emp(name,age,gender,martial,contact,email,location,category,image) VALUES('$name','$age','$gender','$martial','$contact','$email','$location','$category','$image_name')");
        header("Location:index.php?msg=success");
  exit;
    }
}
    ob_end_flush();
 
 if(isset($_GET['msg']))
 {
 ?>
    <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
    <?php 
 }
?>


<form  method="post" name="login" id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table class="table" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Customer Details</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Full Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" required value="<?php echo @$row['name'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="20%">Age</td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['2'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if($result['gender']=="male"){ echo "checked";}?> >
 Male
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($result['gender']=="female"){ echo "checked";}?>>
 Female</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Martial Status</td>
    <td><input name="martial" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['4'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
    <td><input name="contact" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['5'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Email Address</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['6'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Location</td>
    <td><input name="location" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['7'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">category</td>
    <td>
   <select name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo @$row['11'];?>">
    <option <?php if ($selected == 'select' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="select">select</option>
    <option <?php if ($selected == '1' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="1">1</option>
    <option <?php if ($selected == '2' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="2">2</option>
    <option <?php if ($selected == '3' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td width="10%"> Image</td>
    <td><input name="file" type="file" multiple="" ></td>
    
  </tr>
   <?php
   if(isset($row['image'])) 
   {
   ?>
   <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?> " height="50" width="50"></td>
   </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="submit">
    <input name="submit" value="Cancel" type="button" class="submit" onClick="window.location='index.php'">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form> 
<a href="http://dme-medical.com/library/search.php">Go back to list</a>       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer clearfix">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<p>Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p class="art-page-footer">
      
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Your select Query is supposed to be like this :

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query($qry,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
{

}
```

To retrieve radio buttons value from the database :

```
<input type="Radio" name="gender" <?php if ($gender=='male') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
```

To retrieve drop downs you have to echo `selected=selected`.

```
 <select name="category" id="category">
    <option <?php if ($category== '1' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> >1</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '2' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> >2</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '3' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> >3</option>
  </select>
```

A little bit of research would have got you this answer. :) They are all over stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Soumya, I tried this just now but it is not working, my gender radio button problem is same not retrieving in edit form and in drop-down it is taking only first option 1 even at the time of inserting editing and even when i change and update it is  giving 1 as value

Comment: Are $gender and $category the variables you are getting from the database?

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but are the values present in the database? Have you confirmed?

Comment: Yes while inserting they are properly inserted in database but in edit form they are not retrieving values from database both radio buttons are empty non is selected and dropdown in edit forms shows just 1 value and in insert form i have selected 3 but still its showing 1 when i edit

Comment: and when i change the value in dprobox say 2 and when update it again shows one and in database the value is now 1. it changed 3

Comment: and in radio buttons inserting is proper in database but in edit form it does not retrieve any one also and when i try selecting one and update it shows none selected again and in database now its empty

Comment: Your not getting the values from the database in your code. If you are getting them from the database $row['tutorial_id'] where tutorial_id is your column name in the table. Please check on that.

Comment: Yes soumya i have kept this in ming and created names. i checked again on your saying its proper.

Comment: Your mysql query is incomplete.

Comment: mysql_select_db('TUTORIALS');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

Comment: after if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

Comment: where should i end the while close bracket?

Comment: $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query($qry,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
{

}

Comment: You could close it at the end of the file

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm

See the examples over there you'll get an idea

Comment: I closed it before else

Comment: its very big its not coming

Comment: any way to attach file and send

Comment: its coming 4 reputation not yet enough to chat

Answer (score 0):

```html
<--------------------new code start-------------------->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>library</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
    <link href='https://sites.google.com/site/99webdemos/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.responsive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
      jQuery(".form-message").fadeOut(10000);
    });
    </script>
   
<style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
.ie7 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

</style></head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
    <div id="art-header-bg" class="clearfix">
            </div>
    <div id="art-hmenu-bg" class="art-bar art-nav clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<header class="art-header clearfix">


    <div class="art-shapes">
<h1 class="art-headline" data-left="0.5%">
    <a  href="http://www.99demos.blogspot.com" target="_blank">library</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="art-slogan" data-left="87.05%"><a href="http://99demos.blogspot.in/2014/06/createreadupdate-delete-with-image.html"></a></h2>


            </div>

<nav class="art-nav clearfix">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li></ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>

                    
</header>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content clearfix"><article class="art-post art-article">
                                <h2 class="art-postheader">customer form</h2>
                                                
                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <br>
        
        
<?php
ob_start(); 
include('include/connect.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$conn);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 {
 
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
         $age = $_POST["age"];
       $gender=$_POST['gender'];
         $martial = $_POST["martial"];
         $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
               $category= $_POST["category"];
               
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
     $file='uploads/'.$row['image'];
     @unlink($file);
                 $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
              $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
     $image_name=time().".".$ext;
              $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
  }
  else
  {
    $image_name=$row['image'];
  }
  
     $sqlAdd ="update tbl_emp set name='".$name."', age='".$age."', gender='".$gender."', martial='".$martial."', contact='".$contact."', email='".$email."', location='".$location."', category='".$category."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
     mysql_query($sqlAdd);
         header("Location:add.php?id=".@$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
   exit;
    } } 
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
       $age = $_POST["age"];
       $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $martial = $_POST["martial"];
        $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
               $category= $_POST["category"];
              
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
   $image_name=time().".".$ext;

            $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
        }
        $sqlAdd = mysql_query("insert into tbl_emp(name,age,gender,martial,contact,email,location,category,image) VALUES('$name','$age','$gender','$martial','$contact','$email','$location','$category','$image_name')");
        header("Location:index.php?msg=success");
  exit;
    }
}
    ob_end_flush();
 
 if(isset($_GET['msg']))
 {
 ?>
    <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
    <?php 
 
 }
?>


<form  method="post" name="login" id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table class="table" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Customer Details</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Full Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" required value="<?php echo @$row['name'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="20%">Age</td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['2'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
 <td><input type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if ($gender=='male') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Male
 <input type="Radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if ($gender=='female') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Female</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Martial Status</td>
    <td><input name="martial" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['4'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
    <td><input name="contact" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['5'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Email Address</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['6'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Location</td>
    <td><input name="location" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['7'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">category</td>
    <td>
    <select name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo @$row['11'];?>">
    <option <?php if ($category== '1' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="1">1</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '2' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="2">2</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '3' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Image</td>
    <td><input name="file" type="file" multiple="" ></td>
    
  </tr>
   <?php
   if(isset($row['image'])) 
   {
   ?>
   <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?> " height="50" width="50"></td>
   </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="submit">
    <input name="submit" value="Cancel" type="button" class="submit" onClick="window.location='index.php'">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form> 
<a href="http://dme-medical.com/library/search.php">Go back to list</a>       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer clearfix">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<p>Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p class="art-page-footer">
      
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>


</body></html>
<!-------------------------new code end ----------------------------->


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
    my edit.php code 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>library</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
        <link href='https://sites.google.com/site/99webdemos/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
        <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">


        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.responsive.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
          jQuery(".form-message").fadeOut(10000);
        });
        </script>
       

    <style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
    .ie7 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
    .ie6 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

    </style></head>
    <body>
    <div id="art-main">
        <div id="art-header-bg" class="clearfix">
                </div>
        <div id="art-hmenu-bg" class="art-bar art-nav clearfix">
        </div>
        <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
    <header class="art-header clearfix">


        <div class="art-shapes">
    <h1 class="art-headline" data-left="0.5%">
        <a  href="http://www.99demos.blogspot.com" target="_blank">library</a>
    </h1>
    <h2 class="art-slogan" data-left="87.05%"><a href="http://99demos.blogspot.in/2014/06/createreadupdate-delete-with-image.html"></a></h2>


                </div>

    <nav class="art-nav clearfix">
        <div class="art-nav-inner">
        <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li></ul> 
            </div>
        </nav>

                        
    </header>
    <div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                    <div class="art-content-layout">
                        <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                            <div class="art-layout-cell art-content clearfix"><article class="art-post art-article">
                                    <h2 class="art-postheader">customer form</h2>
                                                    
                    <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
        <div class="art-content-layout-row">
        <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
            <br>
            
            
    <?php
    ob_start(); 
    include('include/connect.php'); 
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {

     $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query($qry);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
             $age = $_POST["age"];`enter code here`
             $gender = $_POST["gender"];
             $martial = $_POST["martial"];
             $contact = $_POST["contact"];
             $email = $_POST["email"];
              $location= $_POST["location"];
                              $category= $_POST["category"];
                  
            IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
            {
         $file='uploads/'.$row['image'];
         @unlink($file);
                     $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                  $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
         $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
         $image_name=time().".".$ext;
                  $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
      }
      else
      {
        $image_name=$row['image'];
      }
      
         $sqlAdd ="update tbl_emp set name='".$name."', age='".$age."', gender='".$gender."', martial='".$martial."', contact='".$contact."', email='".$email."', location='".$location."', category='".$category."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
         mysql_query($sqlAdd);
             header("Location:add.php?id=".@$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
       exit;
        }  
    }
    else
    {
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
           $age = $_POST["age"];
           $gender = $_POST["gender"];
            $martial = $_POST["martial"];
            $contact = $_POST["contact"];
             $email = $_POST["email"];
              $location= $_POST["location"];
                             $category= $_POST["category"];
                   
            IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
            {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
       $image_name=time().".".$ext;

                $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
            }
            $sqlAdd = mysql_query("insert into tbl_emp(name,age,gender,martial,contact,email,location,category,image) VALUES('$name','$age','$gender','$martial','$contact','$email','$location','$category','$image_name')");
            header("Location:index.php?msg=success");
      exit;
        }
    }
        ob_end_flush();
     
     if(isset($_GET['msg']))
     {
     ?>
        <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
        <?php 
     }
    ?>


    <form  method="post" name="login" id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <table class="table" width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td width="10%">Customer Details</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="10%">Full Name</td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" required value="<?php echo @$row['name'];?>"></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td width="20%">Age</td>
        <td><input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['2'];?>" ></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Gender</td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if($result['gender']=="male"){ echo "checked";}?> >
     Male
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($result['gender']=="female"){ echo "checked";}?>>
     Female</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="10%">Martial Status</td>
        <td><input name="martial" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['4'];?>" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
        <td><input name="contact" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['5'];?>"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="10%">Email Address</td>
        <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['6'];?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="10%">Location</td>
        <td><input name="location" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['7'];?>" ></td>
      </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td width="10%">category</td>
        <td>
       <select name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo @$row['11'];?>">
        <option <?php if ($selected == 'select' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="select">select</option>
        <option <?php if ($selected == '1' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="1">1</option>
        <option <?php if ($selected == '2' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="2">2</option>
        <option <?php if ($selected == '3' ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="3">3</option>
      </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
     
      <tr>
        <td width="10%"> Image</td>
        <td><input name="file" type="file" multiple="" ></td>
        
      </tr>
       <?php
       if(isset($row['image'])) 
       {
       ?>
       <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?> " height="50" width="50"></td>
       </tr>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="submit">
        <input name="submit" value="Cancel" type="button" class="submit" onClick="window.location='index.php'">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form> 
    <a href="http://dme-medical.com/library/search.php">Go back to list</a>       
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </article></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <footer class="art-footer clearfix">
      <div class="art-footer-inner">
    <p>Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p class="art-page-footer">
          
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    </div>


    </body></html>
```

Comment: You have to call the column names in the while loop.     
tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm
See this tutorial